# How to make my Java "studyFrame" server program available(using my iMac) to all client computers across the internet?

Tags: java, macos, server, client-server, web-hosting

[image: snap shot of two client studyFrames running : drawing on the left(black) is replicated on the other client (blue) -please zoom to check]

- I have built this server-client program in which the client draws on his/her pane and the change is replicated on the other client(s) studyFrame(s)
- **basically I want to test my client-server program out in the real internet(not local network) such that me and my friend(in another city) should be able to use this client-server program.**
- I want my Java server program to be available across the internet and I believe there are two methods one is converting my iMac into a web server and another is using web hosting services.
- iMac mac OS Sierra has removed personal web hosting so I am not able to turn it on and all the articles discussed here on StackOverflow are old so those solutions are not working for my mac.

**My questions are:-**

1) If I want to convert my own iMac into a server(over the internet) how do I go about it(considering the latest mac OS sierra) **without purchasing**  mac OS server software?

2)Are there any **free hosting sites** which allow me to **host the Java server program**(not a website). Please mention all the detailed steps as to how to upload my Java server program on that site and make it available for every client program as I am not well versed in this field!

3)If I buy **mac os Server software** for my iMac will it serve my purpose of making the java server program available to everyone **(mac/windows)** on the internet?

Below is a short part of my Java server's client thread Handler code to get the perspective:

```
     public Handler(Socket socket,int id) {
        this.socket = socket;
       try{ socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);}catch(Exception l) { }
        ID=id;

        //input=new Object[1000];
        try{
         if(out==null)
            {
            // System.out.println("trying to open output streams");
         out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
         //System.out.println("ADDED WRITER....."+"setting requester no="+(frame.w_count+1));
      w_count++;  writers[w_count]=out;out.flush();writers[w_count].flush(); requester=w_count; count++;
       }

        if(in==null){
            //System.out.println("trying to open input streams");
         in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());}

    // System.out.println("opened input stream successfully");



        }catch(Exception k) { System.out.println(k.toString());}
    }



     public void server_out(Object[] inp)
     {


      try{
                int o=0;
                Object[] inpClone=Arrays.copyOf(inp,store);
                    int str=store;
                    store=0;
                for (int u=0;u<(w_count+1);u++) {
                    //System.out.println("sending object to client");

                   //System.out.println("THIS.ID="+this.ID+" and w_count is ="+w_count);

                     if(u!=updateFrom) {writers[u].writeObject(inpClone);
                                      writers[u].flush();}

                     //System.out.println("object sent to client"+u);
                     }





                }catch(Exception k) {System.out.println(k.toString()); }









     }
    public void run() {
        try {

            while(true)
            {

                //System.out.println("RUNNING FROM CLIENT "+requester);

                int o=0;

              synchronized(writers)
               {     
                synchronized(in)
                 {

              //System.out.println("No client update pending");
                    String handOver="#dataHandOver"; 
                  //  System.out.println("Asking Client No. "+requester+" for hand over..");
                     writers[requester].writeObject(handOver);

                    // System.out.println("Trying to read objects from Client No. "+requester);
                    Object test=in.readObject();
                    if(test!=null)
                    {
                    Object rec[]=(Object[])test;
                         input=rec;
                    //System.out.println("creating array upto="+c);
                         //store=c;
                         store=rec.length;
                         updateFrom=requester;
                         server_out(input);

                     }
                        // System.out.println("data dumped");
                    //}
                    //else in.readObject();

            writers[requester].flush();       




                 }
              }
          }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } finally {

            System.out.println("came to finally");

            if (out != null) {
                //writers.remove(out);
            }
            try {
               socket.close(); System.exit(0);
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
    }
```

Comment: This answer here is relevant and should get you started. https://superuser.com/questions/93046/how-do-i-allow-a-remote-user-to-connect-to-a-web-app-running-on-my-pc

Comment: Thanks for the input but exactly how do I use the dynamic DNS service. I have this free DynUDNS .https://www.dynu.com/en-USWhile running a DYNUDNS what IP address should I provide to the socket on the client side?Please mention the exact steps if possible(I am abeginner)